# How to send "this" as a function parameter in a client template of a bound column in an mvc kendo ui grid?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid that has a bound column that uses a client template.  The client template contains an html button with an onclick event and looks like

```
columns.Template(e => e.ConfirmationNumber).ClientTemplate("<button class='btnStartStopClock' onclick='StartStopPSAClock(this, #= ConfirmationNumber #, \"#= Description #\")'>Start</button>").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnStartStop_\\#= ConfirmationNumber\\#" }).Title("").Width(15);
```

I want to know how to properly send 'this' (the button) as a parameter to the onclick function.  What I currently have breaks it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you require by using the below Javascript and by changing your column code as below:

```
columns.Template(e => e.ConfirmationNumber).ClientTemplate("<button class='btnStartStopClock' onclick='StartStopPSAClock(event, #= ConfirmationNumber #, \"#= Description #\")'>Start</button>").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnStartStop_\\#= ConfirmationNumber\\#" }).Title("").Width(15);


function StartStopPSAClock(event, confNumber, descrip) {
    alert("ConfirmationNumber:  " + confNumber);
    alert("Description:  " + descrip);

    //Get Parent Button object as well Parent of Button.
    alert("Button ID: " + event.target.id);
    alert("Button Parent ID: " + event.target.parentElement.id);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pRdsS/9/)**

Comment: perfect, thank you!  i wasn't aware of the event keyword.  Appreciate learning something new.